# Select max() with corresponding field - No Groups

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the highest `revision` (i.e. "2") and the corresponding `Status` (should be "Archived") for `ID=1`, but this query returns "Deleted"

```
SELECT MAX(`Revision`), `Status` FROM `MY_TABLE_NAME` WHERE ID=1
```

```
ID | Revision | Status
1  |   0      | Deleted
1  |   1      | Deleted
1  |   2      | Archived
2  |   0      | ...
2  |   1      | ...
...
```

Can this be done simply, e.g. without using group, join, etc? I would rather not make the query overly complicated, and I feel like it would be inefficient to query for `` MAX(`revision`) `` and then do another query for the `Status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to simply order by the field and take the first result.

```
select Revision, Status from MY_TABLE_NAME where ID=1 order by Revision desc limit 1
```